# why i am not able to print request in YII rest api using postman

Tags: php, yii, yii2, postman

I am making rest API with Yii Plus when I am trying to print_r request (using Postman) it's empty, can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php
 namespace frontend\controllers;
 use Yii;
 use yii\rest\Controller;

 class ApiController extends Controller
{

  Const APPLICATION_ID = 'ASCCPE';
   private $format = 'json';


public function actionUserRegister()
{
   $request = \Yii::$app->request->post(); $post =  (file_get_contents("php://input")); 
   print_r($request);        
   die('sdw');  

}



}
```

Output[image: output in postman]

Answer (score 1):

You are not trying to print request. You are trying to print post data, but you are not sending any post data by your request.

The `\Yii::$app->request->post();` returns data from $_POST array. This array is filled from request body only for data that have been sent in `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

In postman click open the **body** part of request, select one of the two mentioned formats and fill the data you want to send.
If you want to use other format for request, like json or xml, you have to read it from `php://input`. You already have it in your code:

```
$post = (file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

So try to print the `$post` instead of `$request` variable. But you still need to fill the **body** part of request in postman.

The params you've set in postman are the **GET** params. Those are part of request's url. You can get them for example like this:

```
$request = \Yii::$app->request->get();
```

Comment: hi, it is working with GET method only , check here i am using body parameters  https://prnt.sc/sh4hhw

Answer (score 0):

You are returning with the message in the die function.

Instead of this you can try this way:

```
die(print_r($request, true));
```

Example:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request->post();
    die(print_r($request, true));
}
```

[image]

better:

```
return print_r($request, true);
```

Example:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $request = Yii::$app->request->post();
    return print_r($request, true);
}
```

[image]

better:

```
// include the VarDumper class
\Yii::info(VarDumper::dumpAsString($request));
// output will be located in your app.log file
```

More info on the [print_r function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Example:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    return Yii::$app->request->getBodyParams();
}
```

[image]

Comment: try sending the parameters in the body

Comment: use x-www-form-urlencoded instead of the form-data. Also I'm updated the answer with examples from my API, and attached some pictures too

Comment: i did as per your advise , but its not working https://prnt.sc/sea822

Comment: I can think of one more thing. There is a main.php file where the routes, response type and other configurations can be done. In the return array -> [components][response] and [request]: https://prnt.sc/seagdj I have Yii2, so if you are using Yii1 then it might will be different. But this is the part where you can manipulate the request and the response too, so it can be responsible for some issues, but I think it's unlikely

Comment: i am using yii 1